# Python append to list replacing all previous indexes with last value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

In the following Python 3 code, the correct value is written into the `daysSchedule` but when iterating to the next value.

```py
class Data:

    def getDaysSchedule(scheduleUrl, filterTeam = ''):
        with urllib.request.urlopen(scheduleUrl) as request:
            data = json.loads(request.read().decode())
            daysSchedule = GameList()
            for gameData in data["dates"][0]["games"]:
                game = Game()
                game.gameId = gameData["gamePk"]
                game.home.name = gameData["teams"]["home"]["team"]["name"]
                game.away.name = gameData["teams"]["away"]["team"]["name"]
               
                print('\n' + str(game.gameId)) # CORRECT VALUE HERE
                
                daysSchedule.games = daysSchedule.games[:] + [game]  # HERE HAVE TRIED APPEND BUT THAT DIDN'T WORK EITHER

                
                # DEBUG CODE
                menuItems = daysSchedule.games
                for testItem in menuItems:
                    testId = testItem.gameId
                    title = testItem.home.name + ' VS. ' + testItem.away.name
                    print(title)

            return daysSchedule
```

I get output from the debug chunk of code above like the following.   Each one of this is a write out of one of the rows.   And you will see a new row gets added with correct values, but **all the previous rows incorrectly get overwritten with this value** too.

```
633855
Chicago Cubs VS. San Diego Padres
Chicago Cubs VS. San Diego Padres

633834
Arizona Diamondbacks VS. New York Mets
Arizona Diamondbacks VS. New York Mets
Arizona Diamondbacks VS. New York Mets

633853
Baltimore Orioles VS. Minnesota Twins
Baltimore Orioles VS. Minnesota Twins
Baltimore Orioles VS. Minnesota Twins
Baltimore Orioles VS. Minnesota Twins

633882
New York Yankees VS. Tampa Bay Rays
New York Yankees VS. Tampa Bay Rays
New York Yankees VS. Tampa Bay Rays
New York Yankees VS. Tampa Bay Rays
New York Yankees VS. Tampa Bay Rays
```

What in the world is going on -- besides me obviously not having enough caffeine today.

Here is the Games class

```py
class Game(object):
    gameId = '' 
    link = ''
    date = ''
    time = ''
    status = Status()
    home = Team()
    away = Team()
    series = Series()
    venue = Venue()
```

... and the GameList class:

```py
class GameList(object):
    games = [Game()]
```

Comment: May I clarify, is the problem in the repeated printing?

Comment: Show us the code for `class Game()`.  If that is using `[]` as a default parameter, you could see this behavior.  Each instance would be sharing the same list.

Comment: @TimRoberts added the Game and GameList classes above.

Comment: @Ank well they are Models, so printing isn't super helpful, but here ya go... does show a different hex value there for each:

[<models.Game object at 0xb5dc32f0>, <models.Game object at 0xb5dba530>, <models.Game object at 0xb5dba590>, <models.Game object at 0xb5dba5d0>, <models.Game object at 0xb5dba610>, <models.Game object at 0xb5dba650>, <models.Game object at 0xb5dba690>, <models.Game object at 0xb5dba6b0>, <models.Game object at 0xb5dba6d0>, <models.Game object at 0xb5dba710>, <models.Game object at 0xb5dba790>, <models.Game object at 0xb5dba7d0>, <models.Game object at 0xb5dba810>]

Comment: @rawrex yes, clarified the issue in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the trouble came from the way you use classes. Please, note the difference:

This:

```
class Game(object):
    gameId = '' 
    link = ''
    date = ''
    time = ''
    status = Status()
    home = Team()
    away = Team()
    series = Series()
    venue = Venue()
```

Vs.

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gameId = '' 
        self.link = ''
        self.date = ''
        self.time = ''
        self.status = Status()
        self.home = Team()
        self.away = Team()
        self.series = Series()
        self.venue = Venue()
```

In the former ones you have [class attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) which are attributes common **for all instances of this class**. While the later ones are instance attributes, which are attributes **for a particular instance**.

Knowing that, we now see how on each iteration the outer loop adds a new instance of the `Game` class to the instance of `GameList`, while being different objects (with different `id()`, memory locations), they **all share thier class attributes**, i.e. when the program accessed `game.home.name` it was the same for all instances of the `Game` class.

It's like a global variable shared among all class instances that was modified on each iteration, despite creation (independent in any other sense) instances of the class.

By the way, we can have both:

```
class Foo:
    class_attr = 'I am shared among all the instances'
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_attr = 'I belong only to a particular instance'
```

In the second case here, the particular instance will be passed as `self` implicitly.

Comment: Added link to the source code.   I realize the reason for the repetition -- it is correct as I am wanting to see the value of the collection as it is added to.   This is how I discovered the issue that *prior values were being overwritten*.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code I would assume, I got it working. Wait a minute, I will update the answer.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code, please check the new edit. It is solved. :)

Answer (score -1):

You have used the id built-in function as a variable. Change the variable name

Comment: Changed but it has 0 effect.